# Trocar %20 por + na busca via GET

Tags: php, mysqli

Quando faço uma busca via GET através de um formulário a url fica assim:

> teste.com.br?busca.php?q=Frase%20que%20estou%20buscando

gostaria que ficasse assim:

> teste.com.br?busca.php?q=Frase+que+estou+buscando

Alguem sabem como fazer isso?
Referencia: https://www.globo.com/busca/?q=testando+busca

Código do formulário:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="busca.php" method="get" >        
        <div class="form-group" style="width:100%">
            <label for="numero" class="control-label">Busca</label><br>
            <input class="form-control" id="termo" name="termo" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
        </div>
<div class="form-group" style="width:100%">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%!important; padding:6px 12px;"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pesquisar</button>
        </div><!-- /form-group -->
</form>
```

Comment: Ponha o código do form. Note que %20 é correto para URL, e + para form.

Comment: Pode ser simplesmente um `enctype"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` faltando

Comment: Coloquei o código

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tanto o `%20` quanto o `+` são caracteres válidos para representar o espaço,
sendo o primeiro usado em URLs e o segundo em forms, por padrão (por exemplo, na *querystring*).

O `+` era especificado nesta RFC:

> http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html

E depois foi substituido pelo `%20`.

Em PHP mesmo, o `urlencode()` usa `%20`, e para fins de compatibilidade, manteve-se o `rawurlencode()` com o comportamento da RFC 3986.

O que define a formatação de envio do lado do browser é o `enctype`, que não está no seu `form` original:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

Manual

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Form

Pode acontecer de aplicações mais novas usem o `%20` "na marra" (lembrando que num form normal isso é feito pelo *browser* e não do lado PHP). Se faz questão mesmo de usar o `+` por questão de deixar o link com uma estética diferente, independente do *browser*, vai ter que fazer um `POST` para um PHP que dê um *redirect* usando `rawurlencode`, mas eu não recomendaria engessar a aplicação dessa forma.

Comment: Vlw Bacco, funcionou perfeitamente.